# Getting admin password using SQL injection

Tags: sql, sql-injection

I have a website which is vulnerable to SQL injection. It has a username and a password and when we write the username as admin and the password as 'or 1=1-- it logs in saying that you have been successfully logged in as admin. I want to find the password of admin using an SQL injection. What can I do ? Strictly for learning purposes.
I need the password of admin while performing an SQL injection on the username and password fields.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I prevent SQL-injection in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) - Oh wait, you didn't specify your programming language? The key is prepared statements and "?" substitution (parameter binding).

Comment: Not sure us telling you how to exploit this great for you, you should be trying to fix it.

Comment: You shouldn't be storing passwords in clear text in the first place

Comment: @DominicEU I'm training to be an ethical hacker, just beginning.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the poster is asking on how to hack for gaining passwords. He should instead be asking on how to prevent hacking.

Answer (score 1):

Your ability to retrieve the admin password depends on how the password is stored, and how the server-side script that accesses the database is written. If the password is properly salted and hashed, it is virtually impossible to retrieve it; you're simple overriding the system that checks the password. If not, it would still be very difficult and you would need to do a lot of experimentation (see [this answer](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/59097/539) on Information Security Stack Exchange). Either way, you will need to know a lot about the system and how it works in order to attempt such an attack.

Comment: That the override is possible by injecting via the password value implies that the password validation also happens within the same SQL query. And the injected value `'or 1=1-- ` implies that it’s probably in plain text. So blind exfiltration of the plaintext password would probably be possible.

Comment: @Gumbo very good point, however even if a SELECT query can be run, how do you get it to send the results back to you?

Comment: There are certain exfiltration techniques that work with boolean behavior or  even by sending DNS requests (blind out-of-band). Have a look at [my answer to *What is blind injection and how to simulate the issue?*](http://security.stackexchange.com/a/59097/539).

Comment: @Gumbo Interesting, I did not realize that. I will update my answer